# creating two inputs of passwords in css

Tags: css, input, passwords, position, multiple-inheritance

I've tried many attempts to solve this one but I am unable to:
I want to make two sample input boxes with `value="password"` and `value ="Confirm password"`
In such a way that when you click on it the value type is changed from `text` to `password`

I have managed to change one box that is the `password` one but not the `confirm password` one.You see the problem is because of the positioning in the `input[type="password"]`I am only able to add one position to it. When I click on the other `confirm text box` it directly jumps to `password text box`

HTML

```
<input type = "passwords" id="passwords" name="passwords" value ="Password" onclick="passwords();" />
    <input type = "confirm" id="confirm" name="confirm" value ="Confirm Password" onclick="confirms();" />
```

CSS

```
input[type="password"]
{
    background: transparent;
    border:none;
    color:#2185c5;
height:41px;
width:273px;
padding-left:35px;
border-radius:3px;
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;
top:690px;
left:353.5px;
position:absolute;
z-index:11;

    }
```

JS

```
function passwords()
{
    document.getElementById("passwords").value= "";
    document.getElementById('passwords').type = 'password';

}

function confirms()
{
    document.getElementById("confirm").value= "";
     document.getElementById('confirm').type = 'password';

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't type anything in type. `confirm` is not a type, and neither is `passwords`. its `password`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" id="passwords" name="passwords" placeholder="Password" onclick="passwords();" />
<input type="password" id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" onclick="confirms();" />
```

Also, Both of your `password` elements will overlap. Add this at end of your CSS

**CSS**

```
input[type="password"]:nth-child(2) {
    top:690px;
    left:700px;
}
```

Comment: **[The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)** (HTML5 spec). A `label` element associated via `for`/`id` attributes is a correct label for a form field.

Comment: @FelipeAls Thanks for the info. I'll take care of that from now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" />
```

Comment: **[The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)** (HTML5 spec). A `label` element associated via `for`/`id` attributes is a correct label for a form field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your own type. Passwords & Confirm is not a type. Check here for are the available Input Type : [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

This might help you!:)